# Can the Content Query Web Part be used to show all tasks marked as Complete during the current week?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-query-web-part, task-list

I have a dashboard, on which I want to show a list of tasks (from a task list) that have been marked with the status Complete during the current week. Is there a way to do this with the Content Query Web Part? If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use CQWP to show the completed tasks through last week by filtering the following:

- The [Task Status] column equal to `Completed`
- Once the task set to completed, the `[Modified Date]` will be changed to the current date, so you can filter the updated tasks within last week as the following

  ```
  The [Modified Date] Greater Than or Equal to [Today]-7
  ```

**The final filter setting in CQWP should be like this**

[image]

**The output should look like**

[image]

Comment: Any other edits to completed tasks will also show up here, so there is potential (unlikely) that a task completed more than a week ago, but modified in the past week will show up. If you really needed to track that particular modification (status becomes completed) you'll need to include a workflow to track a separate modification column and a previous status column. That is almost definitely overkill and this solution should work perfectly.